# How Handle If all RadioGroup Checked?

Tags: java, android, radio-group

I have RecyclerView With 60 Item. that Items Have RadioGroup and In this Have Two radio button

I use DataBinding Too

I Have FabButton And If Click On THis I will Go To Result Activity But If all RadioGroup Checked :)

I write Like This code And It is work but Has some bug ... When I click On 60th Item Even Do not Check 59 Item I will go to Result Activity.

why ?

This Is My code:

```
//Select All Radio Group
public boolean allSelected() {
    boolean allChecked = true;
    for (Question question : questions) {
        allChecked = question.getSelectedId() != 0;
    }
    return allChecked;
}

//Card background if Uncheck the question
private void showHideErrorBackground(boolean show) {
    for (Question question : questions) {
        question.setShowErrorBackground(show);
    }
    mbtiQuestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

and like it I use This Method :

```
if (allSelected()) {

  Intent intent = new Intent(MbtiQuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);

} else {
        snack bar =
          Snackbar.make(coordinator, R.string.check_all_ques_err, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)

            .setAction(R.string.snack_find_unchecked_ques, new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                showHideErrorBackground(true);
              }
            });

        ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(snackbar.getView(), ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        snackbar.show();
}
```

---

**Question.java (Model data)**

```
public class Question extends BaseQuestion {

  private int selectedId;
  private boolean showErrorBackground;

  @Bindable
  public void setShowErrorBackground(boolean showErrorBackground) {
    this.showErrorBackground = showErrorBackground;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.showErrorBackground);
  }

  @Bindable
  public int getSelectedId() {
    return selectedId;
  }

  public void setSelectedId(int selectedId) {
    this.selectedId = selectedId;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.selectedId);
  }

  public boolean isShowErrorBackground() {
    return showErrorBackground;
  }
}
```

[image]

Thank you for help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `allSelected` method, you are directly setting the value of the variable `allChecked` to be the checked state of the current question in the loop. This means as long as the last question is checked, the value of `allChecked` will be `true`. Similarly, if it weren't checked, it would always be `false`, but that is in line with your app's behaviour, so you might not have faced any issues.

Instead, you should be using an AND operation as follows:

```
allChecked = allChecked && (question.getSelectedId() != 0);
```

Since your `for` loop should break if any question is unanswered, you can optimize the code by doing this:

```
for (Question question : questions) {
      if (question.getSelectedId() == 0) {
          allChecked = false;
          break;
      }
}
```

In this code, `allChecked` will be set to `false` as soon as an unanswered question is encountered, and the rest of the questions will be skipped. You need not use an AND operation each iteration.

Comment: Yes, You Right .. THis Code Correct For me .. Thank a lot dear

Comment: sure .. Just Go to code... After That I check It to accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The boolean returned by this method is just the value of the last question.getSelectedId().

```
public boolean allSelected() {
    boolean allChecked = true;
    for (Question question : questions) {
       allChecked = question.getSelectedId() != 0;
    }
    return allChecked;
}
```

Try this :

```
public boolean allSelected() {
    for (Question question : questions) {
        if (question.getSelectedId() == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, This Is Right too :) Thanks A lot